# Can I make Git use multiple remotes with a specified priority during a clone?

Tags: git

I have a Git repository with 2 remotes:

1. An authoritative remote repository, accessible only over a relatively slow WAN.
2. A mirror of the remote repository available on the local network, to which I have fast access.

I would like to `git clone` the repository as quickly as possible, preferably getting the commits that I can from the local mirror and only reaching out to the authoritative one when needed.

Is it possible to configure Git to do this, preferably with a single `git clone` command? I'm fine with altering my client configuration or environment as needed to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone the local one and then `git fetch` from the farther one.  You can configure groups of remotes which git will fetch in order (see [the docs for `git remote update`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config)), and git doesn't fetch what it already has regardless where it came from.